# Reviewing questions stuck at "Loading next item..." message

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, review

I've already checked to make sure I'm not running in IE7 compatibility mode, which I'm not.

When reviewing questions, regardless of the choice I select ("Not Sure", "Approve", "Recommend for Deletion", etc.), the "Loading next item..." message will appear, but the page will hang and not progress to the next item.

In the bottom left corner of the browser, I noticed a warning, so I clicked it and found the following:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 17 Oct 2012 12:52:57 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
>
> Line: 18
>
> Char: 170
>
> Code: 0
>
> URI: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=b3fa09c1ef3c

If I refresh the browser, the next question/answer for rewview comes up successfully, but when I act on the next question, the "Loading next item" message will hang again.

Comment: Having same issue in IE8 - *seems* to be affecting all review queues on all sites

Comment: @Jim - interesting, and thanks for the update. I just tried this on my Atrix 2's default browser, and I can't reproduce the issue there. It makes me wonder if this is isolated to IE8 only, which may be why this question hasn't been getting much attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact verified and fixed in the next build.  It only impacts IE8 and lower.

Comment: Only does until the next build, or only impacts IE8 and lower after the next build?

Comment: I am currently experiencing this problem with Chrome (latest build)

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem on SO (last night) and now SF.

Comment: Has this build already been installed? I am asking because I am still getting this error with Internet Explorer 8 when navigating to links like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf .