# Review First Posts stuck on "loading item"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I saw [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151684/reviewing-questions-stuck-at-loading-next-item-message), however the answer suggests the problem is only with Internet Explorer and I am having it with Firefox as well.

[image: Screenshot of review loading item notice]

Comment: Maybe a server problem? I saw the same in Chrome but it passed.

Comment: same in IE and there was only one and I was never able to see it

Comment: I've been having this problem with Late Answers and Reopen Votes in Chrome.

Comment: Me too! Except only on First Posts.

Comment: some errors in Low quality posts too, the recommend deletion pop up becomes unresponsive sometimes

Comment: Having spent more time with this issue, it seems to be more hit and miss. I've had problems with Suggested Edits taking a while to load, but never had it completely freeze up. I've also had no issues whatsoever with the Close Votes queue. All the other queues seem to run through phases of consistent freezing (when the items there get reviewed and the queue refills, it seems random whether the newly filled queue will load or continue freezing). I've also started noticing problems where it will start freezing in the middle of reviewing ("loading next item").

Comment: I also have this problem on both Chrome and Firefox since few minutes. After few minutes of loading, I got a `504 Gateway Time-out`. I think the problem might be related to one post that can't be loaded correctly. I'm stuck at *2 First Posts* every time I got one more, I can review it, but then, it endless load for the next one.

Comment: @Random -- sooo... it's a duplicate bug from three months ago that was resolved but has now cropped up again?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to this, but [this recent LQP review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1422717) caught my eye.

Comment: this is not a dupe of that old one, since that old one claims to be fixed. And this came on out of the blue last night and seems to have cleared up on its own today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We were able to find a bug in our code that could lead to a condition where a review task was never returned to the browser.  This was unrelated to [Reviewing questions stuck at "Loading next item..." message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151684/reviewing-questions-stuck-at-loading-next-item-message) - a fix has been pushed and rolled out network wide.  Please let us know if you see this issue again.