# Reviewing error on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review First Posts stuck on “loading item” Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165512/review-first-posts-stuck-on-loading-item-firefox)

Looks that something is going wrong with the review of a post in **First Posts** because it lags and the post didn't appear. It keeps "Loading item...".

When more posts to review appears, you can review until this supposed post. Something is happening. And theres always at least 1 post to review, so looks like nobody can do it.

[image]

Okay, now is happening on **Late Answers** too.

Comment: It would help if you included a link to the specific post that's creating the problem.

Comment: @Yannis The post didn't appear, I don't know wich post is. Thats a supposition.

Comment: Actually, I can't get a link either @Yannis; the same is happening for me...

Comment: @SysDragon Hm, the requests to `review/next-task` and `review/task-reviewed` are the ones that fail to complete (or take quite a while), I can only speculate but it seems the CDN is coughing up (again).

Comment: Yes, looks the same as the post that @hims056 said, but it needs to be fixed now again.

Comment: It may be some server problem , had seen it several times.This won't happen always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this several times today in different queues.

The good part is, the "hanging item" disapears after a few minutes. And if there are more items in the queue, the good items are first.

Comment: You're right. Its fixed now. You know why is this happening sometimes?

Comment: I know they're doing a lot of testing and related work prior to shifting back to the NYC data center, this is _probably_ an artifact of that, but I can't be positive.