# Review queue stuck on 'loading item'

Tags: support, bug

I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165512/review-first-posts-stuck-on-loading-item) and it says the loading problem is solved however lately it happens again in Firefox 44 on Ubuntu 15.04. I've encountered the problem on askubuntu. There are no adblockers, Javascript blockers or whatsoever involved. Can someone please look at it again.

Comment: Which queue is that? Any errors in the dev console on firefox?

Comment: It happens on any review queue I have access to. I don't see any obvious errors when I examine the situation with the Firebug addon.